# Deduplicate table based on createdate

Tags: mysql, query, greatest-n-per-group

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to get my head round a lot of stuff but so far with little success. So I'm trying to get some help, here goes

I have a table "Userdata"

```
Email | FirstName | LastName | CreateDate
a@a.com | aLN | aLN | 01/01/2020
b@b.com | bLN | bLN | 03/01/2020
a@a.com | aLN | aLN | 04/01/2020
```

Basically I want to dedupe the column so that I only get the latest data in that table, so the result would be

```
Email | FirstName | LastName | CreateDate
b@b.com | bLN | bLN | 03/01/2020
a@a.com | aLN | aLN | 04/01/2020
```

I've tried several solutions with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, and JOINS but I can't seem to get this done. The problem I run into is that the table has dozens of columns and I would need to get the values of all of these columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Email FROM "UserData" t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM "UserData" t2 where t1.Email = t2.Email LIMIT 1) AS t2
ON t1.Email = t2.Email
```

This was my latest go at the problem but I get the error "multi-part identifier t1.Email could not be bound"

Comment: `SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName, MAX(CreateDate) CreateDate FROM Userdata GROUP BY Email, FirstName, LastName`

Comment: Thanks Akina, but Is there a way to select all columns. My table has 25 columns and I need all these values. Is there a way to use select * so that I do not have to identify all the fields in my query

Comment: No. Don't be lazy, list all the fields. In general - avoid asterisk except COUNT(*).

Comment: See "groupwise max" or the tag I added.